# Variable has been defined as both character and numeric

Tags: sas

Struggling with a work around for the above error:

> Variable has been defined as both character and numeric

I have an extract that prints a table in SAS which another extract picks up, there are hundreds of micro tables for each day, of which somewhere there is one or two that have numerical values in a column.

My current step looks like this:

```
DATA ALL;
   SET Library.XYZ:;
RUN;
```

The colon looks for anything labelled as `XYZdate9.`;

But when I run the code I get the error on Column A.
Is there a way to either force the column into character or just drop it completely when I merge the tables?

Comment: I guess you dont know which tables are different? Then you could change them all one by one with a simple put-statement in a datastep.

Comment: I dont, there are hundreds of tables, im guessing I could do a proc compare but not sure how I translate that across that many tables.

Comment: How did you create these datasets? Did you use PROC IMPORT?  You can get this type of problem if you use PROC IMPORT because it tries to guess what types of variables you have based on the values it sees. So different subsets of the data could yield different choices.  If you can replace the PROC IMPORT with actual data steps that create the datasets consistently then you will not have this problem at the consolidation step.

Answer (score 0):

## Manual sollution

Assuming you have a problem with problemColumn for XUZbbb, you can write

```
DATA ALL;
SET Library.XYZaaa 
    Library.XYZbbb (rename (problemColumn = problemChar))
    Library.XYZccc ;
```

Now for the observations (rows) from XYZbbb, problemColumn will not have a value (missing value is `.`) but problemChar will have a character representation of the value you need.

```
if problemColumn eq . then problemColumn = input(problemChar, best12.);
RUN;
```

You might need to replace the input format `best12.` with something that fits your data.

## Automated sollution

Write a proc SQL that lists your datasets with the rename for those that need it:

```
PROC SQL;
    select 'Library.'|| memName ||
           case when type = 'char' then ' (rename (problemColumn = problemChar))' 
                else '' end
    into :setsToRead separated by ' '
    from sasHelp.vcolumns
    where libName eq 'LIBRARY' and memName like 'XYZ%' and name = 'problemColumn';
quit;
```

Now use the created macro variable

```
Data ALL;
    Set &setsToRead.;
```

and so forth

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The problem is I cant ascertain which table contains the problem column as there are over 100+ tables names XYZdate. It would mean spending days going through and finding the one or two that are causing the variable error.

Comment: That's where the automated solution is for. I just hope you don't bounce into the maximum length for a macro variable. If so, I do have an alternative.

Comment: By the way, I did not test this.

Comment: Ill try it out. Could you expand on what I'm entering for 'problemchar'? Thanks for taking the time to help

Comment: `memName like 'XYZ%'` is a sql condition, stating memName should be XYZ, followed by anyting else. problemChar is just a temporary variable created by the rename statement.

Comment: The query result from the statement returns a blank page under the SQL sas system results tab!

Comment: You might need to adapt the where clause in SQL to your local situation. For instance, you might need to write ... `and upcase(name) eq 'PROBLEMCOLUMN'` Also check if it is vcolumn or vcolumn**s**

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, you should fix the source so that all columns are the same types as defined by a master schema. Going with the option of just dropping the field, which seems dangerous you can use PROC APPEND with the FORCE option.'

Here's some code to find the problem columns so you can manually fix them.

```
*Code to isolate the variable/tables that may be the issue;
proc sql;
create table variable_types as
select libname, memname, upper(name) as name, type
from sashelp.vcolumn
where libname='WORK' and upper(memname) like 'CLASS%'
order by name, type;

create table variable_mismatch as
select * 
from variable_types
where name in (select name from variable_types group by name having min(type) ne max(type));
quit;
```

And here's some code if you simply want to drop the variables that would need to be put into a macro loop.

```
*Create sample datasets;
data class;
set sashelp.class;
run;

data class2;
set sashelp.class(rename=age=age_num);

age=put(age_num, 2.);
run;

*Append via data step - generates error;
data want;
set class class2;
run;

*Append via proc append;
proc append base=class data=class2 force;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

The SQL dictionary information can help you identify the variables that have multiple types across the tables of a library.

It's up to you how to deal with the issue.  Either convert everything to character or make corrections to the micro datasets to ensure a consistent type.  A robust solution would compute an ATTRIB statement that ensures the length of all common variables are long enough to prevent truncation.

Example:

```
data one;
  xxx = 'a';
  a = 'a';
data two;
  XXX = 1;
  b ='b';
data three;
  xXx = 'ccc';
  a='a';
  b='C';
run;

proc sql;
  create table variables_with_differing_types as
  select libname, memname, name, type
  from dictionary.columns
  where libname = 'WORK'
  group by libname, upcase(name)
  having min(type) ne max(type)
  ;
```

[image]

You may want to add master control table (i.e. metadata table) to your dataflow that specifies the types of each variable, and code a pre-program that enforces a policy that the micro datasets must conform to the master table.